# how to find a point(vector2) between two points(Vector2) of a line (line renderer)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, linear-algebra, vectormath

As the question explains, how to find a point(vector2) between two points(Vector2) of a line (line renderer),

[image: Example]

I am using a line renderer to draw the line with two points (start with vector and endpoint), what I want is that want point A in the line as you can see in the image.

In theory, I want to shorten the line from the original length for my use case, I am doing a line intersection check for two lines overlapping, but the problem is that in some cases the lines start from the same point, and in those situations, if the points meet, it still counts as a line intersection. So in theory I want to shorten the line for line intersection check so it doesn't intersect with the other line if the points meet.

Here is the script for my line intersection check!

```
  public bool isIntersecting = false;
  LineRenderer lineRenderer;
 
     private void Start()
     {
         lineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
     }
 
     private void Update()
     {
         LineRenderer recievedLine;
         if (FindObjectOfType<LineDynamics>().ropeRenderer != null)
         {
             recievedLine = FindObjectOfType<LineDynamics>().ropeRenderer;
         }
         else
         {
             return;
         }
 
         AreLineSegmentsIntersectingDotProduct(lineRenderer.GetPosition(0), lineRenderer.GetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1), recievedLine.GetPosition(0), recievedLine.GetPosition(recievedLine.positionCount - 1));
     }
 
     //Line segment-line segment intersection in 2d space by using the dot product
     //p1 and p2 belongs to line 1, and p3 and p4 belongs to line 2 
     public bool AreLineSegmentsIntersectingDotProduct(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3, Vector2 p4)
     {
 
         if (IsPointsOnDifferentSides(p1, p2, p3, p4) && IsPointsOnDifferentSides(p3, p4, p1, p2))
         {
             isIntersecting = true;
         }
         else
         {
             isIntersecting = false;
         }
 
         return isIntersecting;
     }
 
     //Are the points on different sides of a line?
     private bool IsPointsOnDifferentSides(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3, Vector2 p4)
     {
         bool isOnDifferentSides = false;
 
         //The direction of the line
         Vector2 lineDir = p2 - p1;
 
         //The normal to a line is just flipping x and z and making z negative
         Vector2 lineNormal = new Vector2(-lineDir.y, lineDir.x);
 
         //Now we need to take the dot product between the normal and the points on the other line
         float dot1 = Vector2.Dot(lineNormal, p3 - p1);
         float dot2 = Vector2.Dot(lineNormal, p4 - p1);
 
         //If you multiply them and get a negative value then p3 and p4 are on different sides of the line
         if (dot1 * dot2 < 0f)
         {
             isOnDifferentSides = true;
         }
 
         return isOnDifferentSides;
     }
```

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well which point is the one you want to get? The center between them or just any point on the line?

Comment: I want any point in the line. So basically you can say, the point between two vectors.
@derHugo

Comment: I did not understand your question? Can't you just make a if check if both lines start or end from same points and just return a false?

Comment: No @Xentios, the thing is the lines are drawn dynamically, and there can be any number of lines, be it from 10 to 50. In that case, if I have to check for each line if the points are met will be really expensive update.

The simplest solution I could think of was to get the vectors in line a bit far from their start and end and use that to calculate for line intersection instead.

Comment: @BhavinLathia 50 `Vector3 ==` checks is nothing actually  compared to calculating 50 line intersections ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To your question

You could e.g. use [`Vector2.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) in order to get any point between your start and end point given a factor between `0` and `1` where

- `0`: equal to start point
- `1`: equal to end point
- `{0;1}`: equal to linear interpolation between start and end

For the center it would e.g. be

```
var center = Vector2.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, 0.5f);
```

---

If you rather need a certain travel distance from the start point you could use [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) like

```
var otherPoint = Vector2.MoveTowards(startPoint, endPoint, desiredDistanceFromStartPoint);
```

---

Basically you also can go fully manual and basically do the same like

```
var direction = (endPoint - startPoint).normalized;
var otherPoint = startPoint + direction * desiredDistanceFromStartPoint;
```

This however, doesn't protect you from overshooting the endPoint.

---

#### To your actual problem

You know that there is already functions implemented by the Unity community long ago under [Wiki - Math functions](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions) which already provides e.g.

```
//Calculate the intersection point of two lines. Returns true if lines intersect, otherwise false.
//Note that in 3d, two lines do not intersect most of the time. So if the two lines are not in the 
//same plane, use ClosestPointsOnTwoLines() instead.
public static bool LineLineIntersection(out Vector3 intersection, Vector3 linePoint1, Vector3 lineVec1, Vector3 linePoint2, Vector3 lineVec2){

    Vector3 lineVec3 = linePoint2 - linePoint1;
    Vector3 crossVec1and2 = Vector3.Cross(lineVec1, lineVec2);
    Vector3 crossVec3and2 = Vector3.Cross(lineVec3, lineVec2);

    float planarFactor = Vector3.Dot(lineVec3, crossVec1and2);

    //is coplanar, and not parrallel
    if(Mathf.Abs(planarFactor) < 0.0001f && crossVec1and2.sqrMagnitude > 0.0001f)
    {
        float s = Vector3.Dot(crossVec3and2, crossVec1and2) / crossVec1and2.sqrMagnitude;
        intersection = linePoint1 + (lineVec1 * s);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        intersection = Vector3.zero;
        return false;
    }
}

//Two non-parallel lines which may or may not touch each other have a point on each line which are closest
//to each other. This function finds those two points. If the lines are not parallel, the function 
//outputs true, otherwise false.
public static bool ClosestPointsOnTwoLines(out Vector3 closestPointLine1, out Vector3 closestPointLine2, Vector3 linePoint1, Vector3 lineVec1, Vector3 linePoint2, Vector3 lineVec2){

    closestPointLine1 = Vector3.zero;
    closestPointLine2 = Vector3.zero;

    float a = Vector3.Dot(lineVec1, lineVec1);
    float b = Vector3.Dot(lineVec1, lineVec2);
    float e = Vector3.Dot(lineVec2, lineVec2);

    float d = a*e - b*b;

    //lines are not parallel
    if(d != 0.0f){

        Vector3 r = linePoint1 - linePoint2;
        float c = Vector3.Dot(lineVec1, r);
        float f = Vector3.Dot(lineVec2, r);

        float s = (b*f - c*e) / d;
        float t = (a*f - c*b) / d;

        closestPointLine1 = linePoint1 + lineVec1 * s;
        closestPointLine2 = linePoint2 + lineVec2 * t;

        return true;
    }

    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And as said if your concern is actually the start point being equal for two lines (very unlikely) doing 50 `Vector3 ==` checks is very cheap compared with the rest of calculations you are doing anyway.

Comment: Okay, I am seriously very sorry. I am the dumbest person alive. I don't understand why I wanted to complicate things : p Now I understand what you mean by doing `Vector3 ==` checks

I genuinely apologize for wasting everyone's time. I feel so dumb right now. 

All I had to do was before even performing line intersection, I just had to check if the start point/ endpoint is near to the start point/ endpoint of another line, If they are then just skill things altogether. I am genuinely very sorry. I have no idea why did I want to overcomplicate things?

Thank you so much for your reply!